# How do I use "usemap" with bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

My usemap is only working for the first slide. All slides after that have no usemaps attached, it's very weird.

```html
<map name="kubota-desktop-map">
                    <area target="_blank" alt="Kubota-Details" title="" href="google.com" coords="70,1025,342,1097" shape="rect">
                    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="google.com" coords="358,1025,633,1097" shape="rect">
                    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="https://www.kubotausa.com/ " coords="1564,1009,1939,1113" shape="rect">
                </map>              
                <map name="kubota-mobile-map">
                    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="https://www.kubotausa.com/finance/special-offers" coords="29,475,176,515" shape="rect">
                    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="google.com" coords="184,476,332,515" shape="rect">
                    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="google.com" coords="389,468,575,521" shape="rect">
                </map>
                
                <map name="tractor-desktop-map">
                    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="google.com" coords="1215,1039,1490,1113" shape="rect">
                    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="google.com" coords="1602,1032,1932,1129" shape="rect">
                </map>
                <map name="tractor-mobile-map">
                    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="google.com" coords="118,508,255,545" shape="rect">
                    <area target="_blank" alt="" title="" href="google.com" coords="313,505,476,551" shape="rect">
                </map>
                
                
                
                
<!-- Carousel -->
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                    <div class="normal">
                        <img src="img/slide/kub_1.jpg" alt="First slide" usemap="#kubota-desktop-map">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mobile">
                        <img src="img/slide/kub_2.jpg" alt="First slide" usemap="#kubota-mobile-map">
                    </div>
                              <!-- Static Header -->
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                    <div class="normal">
                        <img src="img/slide/trac_1.jpg" alt="Second slide" usemap="#tractor-desktop-map">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mobile">
                        <img src="img/slide/trac_2.jpg" alt="Second slide" usemap="#tractor-mobile-map">
                    </div>
     
                  
                </div>
                
              </div><!-- /carousel -->
```

So yea, the usemap works fine on the first slide, the others do not work though. If I remove the usemap from the first slide, it works on the second. This makes no sense to me, not sure if its because of the carousel or not.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you include a link to the (partially) working carousel? Also—whoa, `usemap` takes me way back.